# In QT5/C++ what to pass as FILE * parameter

Tags: c++, qt5

I have functions which take a FILE* as parameter so normally I can pass stdout as parameter.
However I would like to directly pass QInfo() for example.
Is there a way to do this ?

For example library function with signature

```
void print_server_info(FILE *fd, const server_info_t *si)
```

Is there anyway to pass a QT object or underlying attribute so that I don't have to pass stdout ?

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Do you mean the [`qInfo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qInfo) function? It's not a stream by itself. Pas the `FILE*` you want the output to be written to (`stdout`, `stderr` or to some file you opened yourself).

Comment: There's nothing in the standard to help, but on linux you have [fopencookie](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopencookie.3.html) to forward `fopen` API calls to callbacks, which you could use to pass the data.

Comment: I think you can use [`QLocalSocket`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html) to connect to a pipe, and have the other end write to `qInfo()`. On Unix, `QLocalSocket::socketDescriptor()` returns a file descriptor